SSH RunCommand and Execute command hangs on but the client connection (using putty) works and executes command
I am trying to execute the ssh client command using SshNet package. Below codes hangs on RunCommand and Execute command and it won't execute the command on target device.

Using RunCommand

using (var duclient = new SshClient("ipaddress", 22, "admin", "admin")){
    duclient.Connect();
    string poweroff = duclient.RunCommand("show outlets").Result;
    Console.WriteLine(poweroff);
    duclient.Disconnect();
    duclient.Dispose();
}


Using CreateCommand and Execute

using (var duclient = new SshClient("ipaddress", 22, "admin", "admin")){
   duclient.Connect();
   SshCommand command = duclient.CreateCommand("show outlets");
   command.Execute();
   duclient.Disconnect();
   duclient.Dispose();
}

But the manual connection using putty works and able to execute the commands. Below are the reference images.








I am not understanding the issue with the code. How can I resolve the problem?

Won't solve your issue, just a note: you do not need to call Dispose() in an using block on the object referenced in the using's brackets.

got it.. thank you..

Have you checked the other properties of duclient.RunCommand returned object, such as Error? Also use await with the async functions instead.

It looks like you're making an ssh connection to a specialized network device of some kind--a remote power controller?--rather than a general-purpose computer. It's possible this device doesn't implement the ssh feature that you're trying to use here.
When you run a command such as ssh user@host, ssh opens what is sometimes called a "shell" channel with the remote system. A shell channel acts like an interactive terminal. On a unix system, the remote ssh process will start your login shell; you can send commands to it and see their output.
When you run a command such as ssh user@host 'show outlets', ssh opens what is called an "exec" channel. It executes the specific command which you requested. You can send input to the command and see its output. When the command exits, the exec channel closes.
I'm not a C# programmer, but the C# code in your question is probably opening an exec channel, while your putty example is using a shell channel. I expect the device you're connecting to doesn't support exec channels correctly.
To connect to the remote system with a shell session, it looks like you'd call SshClient.CreateShellNoTerminal() or SshClient.CreateShell(), then write your command string (followed by a newline or carriage return) into the channel. The shell channel probably won't automatically close after the command executes, so you'll have to deal with capturing the output and closing the channel yourself.
